# Nuget fails to manage references in a project cloned from git

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, git, nuget

I created a project (asp mvc 4) and used nuget to add dlls to it. Than I committed it to bitbucket and finally cloned to a different directory on the same PC. In the cloned project every single reference shows an error (yellow exclamation mark)

[image]

I allowed nuget to manage packages:

[image]

I also have nuget files in my solution:

[image]

Right after cloning there's no 'packages' folder in my solution, but after first attempt to build it appears and if filled with dlls. My .gitignore:

```
#NuGet
packages/
```

How do I make it work?

**EDIT**

Build output (btw the build took a few **minutes** and after it failed the whole VS froze - I couldn't even copy the error messages) :

When I right-click on any of the references and go to properties the 'Path' is empty.

[image]

my .csproj:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
          <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

this file actually exists in the given location.

Comment: What warnings do you observe in VS's Error List?

Comment: @abatishchev Please see the edit section.

Comment: Did you commit your packages.config file?

Comment: @AndrzejGis every time I clone my git repository, I have the yellow exclamations on all my nuget and binary references from my repo. I need to click properties on any of the exclamation references in question, and all these references in the project will update and remove the exclamation. I need to do this for every project in my solution. After closing and reopening the solution, it will usually build. Just some clicking in VS without actually changing seems to "fix" it. But I wish there were a more automatic solution.

Comment: I don't know why, but the problem solved when I ran Visual Studio again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is functioning as it should.  (Do you see any errors other than the yellow exclamation icon?)  The only thing that's weird is the remaining yellow icons.  This is most likely just a refresh issue.  Either push refresh at the top of the solution window (the two arrows), or close and reopen the solution.  You'll find the yellow exclamation points are gone, and all is well.

Alternatively, commit the packages folder and remove the line in .gitignore, though I grant you've previously chosen not to do this.

**Edit:**

Another thought: you could get this experience if you opened up the solution on a machine that didn't have .net 4.5 or asp.net mvc 4 installed.

Comment: Please see the edit, I submitted the error. "Alternatively, commit the packages folder and remove the line in .gitignore" I've already used that workaround, but I guess it's not the right way to go. As far as I know avoiding including dlls in a repo is one of the nuget's goals.